# MVC 5 DataAnnotations not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I have used DataAnnotations in MVC 4 projects and it works good including client validation.

I am starting a MVC 5 project but I am having problems with DataAnnotations and validation.
The MVC 4 project didn't use Bootstrap and this new one uses Bootstrap 3 but I doubt that is the issue. The dates are not formatted and the Note field is not required even though that is specified. ModelState shows valid even though the notes field is empty.

**My view**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OnGoing, new
       {
           @class = "control-label col-md-2"
       })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OnGoing)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OnGoing)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes, new
       {
           @class = "control-label col-md-2"
       })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Notes, 10, 150, null)*@
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**web.config**

```
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

**partial class for DataAnnotations**

```
 [MetadataType(typeof(CaseFormatting))]
public partial class MetaCase
{
}

public class CaseFormatting
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime CreatedDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime UpdatedDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="required")]
    public string Notes
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Bundles

```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the DataAnnotations not working, my mistake was that the partial class was named MetaCase instead of Case.

For the unobtrusive validation not working, I referenced the jqueryval js but not the jquery.unobtrusive in my bundle. This is how is should look:

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                               "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                               "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```